# Flutter - losing Provider state on hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-provider, hot-reload

When I hot-reload my app, I lose state from my Provider classes. I'm aware that Provider properly preserves state so I know the issue comes from my code, but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. I have the following:

---

**main.dart**

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: GlobalData.fetchTheme(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> themeSnapshot) {
        if (themeSnapshot.hasData) {
          GlobalData.theme = themeSnapshot.data;
          return Phoenix(
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'MyApp',
              home: Scaffold(body: Root()),
              theme: ThemeData(
                accentColor: Palette.green
              ),
            )
          );
        }
        return Loading();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

---

**root.dart**

```dart
class Root extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FireAuth().getInstance().onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
          if (user != null) {
            GlobalData.setUid(user.uid);
          }
          return user == null ? Auth() : SafeArea(child: KeyboardDismisser(child: Core()));
        } else {
          return Loading();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

**core.dart**

```dart
class Core extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder(
          future: Users.getUser(GlobalData.uid),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<TuneUser> userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserProvider(userSnapshot.data)),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SearchProvider()),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DetailsProvider()),
                ],
                child: Expanded(child: BottomBarNavigation())
              );
            }
            return Expanded(child: Loading());
          }
        ),
        BottomBar()
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

---

I assume at some point I'm rebuilding or losing state when I shouldn't, I've tried a lot of things with the help of similar questions already present, but I can't seem to fix it.

Any ideas?
Would really appreciate the help.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap you `MultiProvider` in the main.dart

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserProvider(userSnapshot.data)),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SearchProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DetailsProvider()),
  ],
  child: child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'MyApp',
    home: Scaffold(body: Root()),
    theme: ThemeData(
      accentColor: Palette.green
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: set your data later in  UserProvider with userSnapshot.data

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks. What is the reasoning for this? What was causing the state to be lost?

Comment: i am sorry i don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't enough using MultiProvider class. You need to register the providers like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => User())
```

not like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: User())
```